# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'test' to data type int error but the CONVERT function is in a CASE statement that is not hit

Tags: sql

I'm having a problem where I'm getting a 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '' to data type int.' error but the only piece of code with a CONVERT is in a CASE which is never hit.

```
create table #temp (id int identity(1,1), optionType int, data varchar(100))
insert into #temp
values
(1,'test'),
(1,'1234'),
(1,'1234'),
(2,'12345'),
(2,'5435435')

select
case optionType
    when 1 then data
    when 2 then data                
    when 3 then CONVERT(INT, LEFT(data, CHARINDEX('_', data) - 1))          
end 
from #temp

drop table #temp
```

Why does the error occur ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select
case optionType
    when 1 then data
    when 2 then data                
    when 3 then LEFT(data, CHARINDEX('_', data) - 1)          
end 
from #temp
```

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Thanks. yes it can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

All "when" of a case must return the same type.

You're trying to return INT and VARCHAR.

You'll have to choose !

sample working code (with your entries)

```
select
case optionType
    when 1 then data        
end as stringData,
case optionType
   when 2 then convert(INT, data)  
end as numericData
from #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to achive this logic, you should separate you CASE... WHEN structure into two different column for both return type (varchar and int):

```
select
case optionType
    when 1 then data
    when 2 then data
end as VarcharValue,
case optionType
    when 3 then CONVERT(INT, LEFT(data, CHARINDEX('_', data) - 1))        
end as IntValue
from #temp

drop table #temp
```

Or if you need this for an application, you should solve the conversation in your datamodel or businesslogic layer.